# Python CGI redirect returns "End of script output before headers"

Tags: python, redirect, apache2, cgi

I am trying to build a redirect service that will allow me to track clicks within emails I send to foreign websites.

Example of the URL of this script:

https://example.com/cgi-bin/redir.py?rurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fde&utm_content=test

I am using Apache2 on Ubunut20.04 with the cgi module, calling the following redir.py script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import webbrowser
  
redirect_url = "https://www.example.com"
webbrowser.open(redirect_url)
```

Now this results in the following error:

```
End of script output before headers: redir.py
```

Adding a header:

```
print('Content-Type: text/plain')
print('')
print('hello world')
```

With this "hello world" output I get exactly this, a "hello world" message.

How to redirect if a header is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you print gets returned to the requesting browser. Your python file should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
print()
print("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=TARGETURL\" />")
```